# Natural Rights in Dharmashastras

Tags: dharma-shastras, nature, rights

During the Enlightenment, John Locke proposed a series of natural rights all humans are entitled does Dharmashastras have something similar.

Comment: The Indic framework (particularly dharmaśāstrika) isn't *right-based* in nature unlike the west. The dharmaśāstrika framework is based on dharma, which in nothing like 'right' exactly.

Comment: @Bingming okay, but aren't their basic rights a human being is entitled to if not why would their not be seeing as while all human beings aren't equal we have an equal part of ourselves certainly shouldn't their be some uniformity?